# Resize UILabel in UITableViewCell looks jumpy

Tags: iphone, uitableview, resize, uilabel

For the `textLabel` of a `UITableViewCell`, I start with a height that could just show two lines of text. If the actual height (size) needed for a given label/text is longer than that, user can tap on the cell (for example) to expand it's height such that the whole text can be shown. I have managed to get that work by doing `[tableView beginUpdates];` and `[tableView endUpdates];` on the selected row, at the same change the height of the row accordingly.

But the problem that I see so far is that, visually the resize happens on both directions (upward and downward) instead of just downward which is what I expected. Is there anyway to fox that behavior?

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724190/ios-custom-table-view-cell-label-resizing-corruption. You will need to give correct height to your label. because text in it is aligned in middle-verticle.

Comment: Thanks @ravin. But it's a different issue.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can provide screenshot.

Comment: @Ravin, the problem that I see so far is that, visually the resize happens on both directions (upward and downward) instead of just downward which is what I expected. Sorry I don't know how could I make a screenshot out of that behavior.

Comment: As I said the text in label has middle vertical-alignment. So if the size increases the text will try to remain at middle. One quick fix for this can be that you append new line character(\n) in the string as per the height required so your text will move up.

Comment: thanks, that explains it. i will give it a try with the trick.